# No puedo imprimir la 10ma linea

Tags: python

```
usuario = input("Usuario: ")
clave = input("Clave: ")

if usuario == "admin" and clave == "password":  
   
    print("Inicio exitoso")
    
autenticacion = int(input("Ingrese la hora de su autenticacion: "))

if 7 >= autenticacion <= 19:

    print("valido")

else:

    print("Usuario, clave incorrectos o se encuentra en un horario no establecido")
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes la condición al reves:

```
if 7 <= autenticacion <= 19:
```